# How do I find out which AWS ACCESS KEY ID was used to launch an instance?

Tags: amazon-web-services

I would like to create a tool that will monitor AWS for unused instances and then send an email to the user that launched the instance asking them to shut it down if they aren't using it.

Assuming I have a database with a mapping between Access Key ID's and the email addresses of the users at our company that launch EC2 instances, how can I find the Access Key ID of a running EC2 instance?

Are there any existing software or services that already do this?

Comment: Janitor Monkey by Netflix is what you are looking for go through this article http://techblog.netflix.com/2013/01/janitor-monkey-keeping-cloud-tidy-and.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do this - there is not always a relationship between a user and a running instance.

Think about autoscaling:  an instance can come online in response to an event, run for a few hours, and then go away.  No human intervention needed.

You may be able to pull some information about the user that created it by turning on CloudTrail, but it won't identify which key was used.  Remember than users can have multiple keys.

If you really want to ensure that you can track who is launching instances, put in a policy to require a specific tag (say, "Owner") with an email address, and terminate any instances that don't have the tag set. (You should be able to do this with AWS Config rules)

Comment: CloudTrail actually records which Access Key was used for each request. See: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/awscloudtrail/latest/userguide/cloudtrail-event-reference-user-identity.html#cloudtrail-event-reference-user-identity-fields . But, anyways, I agree with you that it's not an ideal way to track who did what -- as you mentioned, users can have multiple keys, and those can be rotated; in addition to that, there are temporary keys of all sorts, so not really practical way to track who did what.

Comment: @BrunoReis CloudTrail records the iam user which is sufficient to track the actions.

Comment: @helloV, yes -- the same docs page linked above explain that in detail. I was just commenting on chris' message that said "it won't identify which key was used" -- it does.

Comment: @BrunoReis - I was thinking about keys linked to an IAM account - in the case of temporary credentials, or automated events, the userIdentity section of the CloudTrail event may not even have an API Key

Comment: Thanks again @chris for this spot-on answer!  For tag policy enforcement I'm currently using github.com/capitalone/cloud-custodian because it is very feature-rich and has the ability to message people and give them chance to retroactively tag before shutting down.  (not sure if AWS Config does this, but curious)

Answer (score 1):

All instances will have a IAM user associated with it. You can get this information from CloudTrail but it will show the trail for the last 2 weeks so you need to periodically collect the data and store it.

The way I do is: I use a combination of CloudTrail + Lambda and tag the instance when the instance is started. The Tag can be a name or email. When I see unused instance(s), I queried the tag and send email identified by the tag. It works flawlessly. I posted it as a question: [Mandatory tagging when launching EC2 instance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31867803/mandatory-tagging-when-launching-ec2-instance)

Check the accepted answer posted by me. It was fun learning about AWS Lambda. The Lambda usage falls below free tier limit and I pay nothing for using AWS Lambda.